# How To Create a Polymorphic Array in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, oop, polymorphism

I want to create an array of an abstract class, and call some run() method on each of the array's elements, which reference an implementation of that class.

In something like Java (Forgive the syntax please, this is just to make a point), the code would be something like:

```
abstract class Base{
    public void run();
}

class Derived0 extends Base{
    public void run(){...};//overrides Base's run() method
}

class Derived1 extends Base{
    public void run(){...};//overrides Base's run() method
}

class Derived2 extends Base{
    public void run(){...};//overrides Base's run() method
}
```

main:

```
Base baseArray[3];
baseArray[0] = new Derived0();
baseArray[1] = new Derived1();
baseArray[2] = new Derived2();

//runs each possible run() method, without main knowing any of them.
for(int i=0;i<3;++i){
    baseArray.run();
}
```

**I want to achieve this behavior in matlab**

What I have so far is the accepted answer to this question:

[Inheritence Polymorphism In Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269552/inheritence-polymorphism-in-matlab)

What I lack is how to make the array baseArray?

things like `baseArray = []` cause `baseArray(1) = Derived0;` to expect double, thus fail.

It is impossible to instantiate an array of Base in matlab, becasue the class is abstract, and no instances can be created with matlab's way of creating object arrays (that I know of).

so, please help me achieve a polymorphic array in Matlab.

I would also appreciate a python solution, although a Matlab solution is best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MATLAB, if you instantiate the array with `baseArray = []`, then you're already declaring that the array is going to be of type `double` so it won't work. Instead, you can use the [`empty` method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) of your classes to create an empty array *of that class*.

```
baseArray = Derived0.empty();
baseArray(1) = Derived0();
```

Alternately, you could just create the array at once

```
baseArray = [Derived0(), Derived0(), Derived0()];
```

Also, if you want to have a heterogeneous array of objects, you'll want to make sure that your base class also inherits from [`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous-class.html) and then you can do

```
baseArray = [Derived0(), Derived1(), Derived2()];
```

Comment: nice! but - what if i want my array to be  instantiated with a fixed size n and not grow each time i add an element? your first method makes it grow, and the second doesn't allow variable size

Comment: @Gulzar That is not possible in MATLAB. The only way to have a pre-allocated array would be to fill it with *actual* objects as in my second example and then replace them with new objects. You *could* create an array of references to the *same* object to instantiate it. There is some more relevant info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35899875/not-enough-input-arguments-error-when-creating-an-array-of-custom-objects/35901096#35901096)